# How to fire a sqlite query after some duration specified in android

Tags: android

I am just trying to fire a sql query to delete some data from db in my application. The point is that the sql query is going to be fire after some specified duration(like some days 1 or 2 days), in that time my application  may be in idle state...

Comment: Is it correct to assume that your app will not be idle when the SQL query should be fired?

Comment: No simon... As i already mentioned that whether the app is idle or active, Once the scheduled time will reach, it will fire the sql query to delete the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use android [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html).

Schedule a Receiver that will be fired at specific time as you needed and in onReceive write code for deleting from datbase

Set the alarm like

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,
                0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, triggerTime, pendingIntent
```

);

and in the receiver write code for deletion

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // code to delete from db
            }

    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your valuable suggestion... Just imagine a situation where, I am storing the username and password of my user immediately after login in local db.. And i want to delete it from db once the user completes it login session for 2 days... Like this more than 1 user can login to my app in one device... So how can i implement it to delete user data from db according to there session.....

Comment: You can do it in number of ways.One way is checking the saved time in onReceive of the alarm receiver.You will see what pairs of user name and id will be deleted.Assuming you wrote login time in your local db.Another way can be just putting user id as put extra in the intent of the receiver.Then you can check it in onReceive

Comment: Thanks, i got it... Let me try

Comment: Hi rasel.. I have an small issue.. Every time the delete query is only deleting the last user which login the application... Why it is not taking other users those logged in before.....

Comment: what you need.delete all users who already logged in?. Then write delete query to delete All

Comment: i wanna delete each user after every days 2. For eg User A logs in and his time is started for 2 days, then after the first day User B logs in. So after the 2nd day User A data should be deleted then after 3rd day User B data should be deleted. It has to be a parallel case.

Comment: okay.you can set an alarm for each login that will be triggered after two days and will delte the entry.Or you can triggered an alarm every day and check which entry is old by two days then can delete them